# In VB.NET, is IMPLICIT variable declaration (= New) allowed for all types of variable?

Tags: vb.net, variable-declaration

I translated a Java program to VB.net. The program has been built without error.

When I execute the program for first time, the program crashes on following line

```
If oEnvironMap.isEmpty() Then
```

indicating that

```
System.MissingMemberException : public member 'isEmpty' from 'SortedDictionary(Of String,String)' type is not foundable
```

where `oEnvironMap` declaration line is following

```
Private oEnvironMap = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
```

If I add `as` word as in following code

```
Private oEnvironMap as SortedDictionary(Of String, String) = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
```

building application return a lot of errors on methods used with `oEnvironMap`.

Personnally, I thought that declaring a VB.Net variable using implicit declaration is allowed.

I now see that is not working for complex array as Dictionary !

Is that a bug in Visual Studio Community 2019 that I can communicate to MSDN or it is simply a personal misunderstanding ?

Comment: Implicit declarations are allowed in VB.NET. But `SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` offers no `IsEmpty` method. My guess is you also have `Option Strict Off` which allows late binding. Turn it on by wirting `Option Strict On` in your file as the first statement, event before imports. You could also hover over `oEnvironMap` and see what object type Visual Studio detects.

Comment: It seems that you have assumed that a member that does exist in Java also exists in .NET. There is no such member so assuming that there is is the issue here. Whether or not you specify the type of a variable or whether it is inferred as `Object` or some other type has no bearing on what members an object has at run time.

Comment: You absolutely should be specifying the type of every variable though. You should have `Option Strict` set to `On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it is `On` by default for every future project. If you are getting errors when you specify the type it is because you have written bad code that incorrectly uses that type, not because VS is broken. Try reading the documentation to see what members that type has and what equivalents may be for those that exist only in Java.

Comment: @jmcilhinney *You absolutely should be specifying the type of every variable though* - with this are you asserting that inference should never be used and `Dim s = "Hello world"` should always be `Dim s as String = "Hello world"` ?

Comment: Also bear in mind that while .NET may once have been what Microsoft created to salvage some of the millions of dollars of R&D effort they put into creating their own flavour of Java before Sun kicked them in the nuts and they took their ball home, the two languages are nothing to do with each other, and one cannot simply hope that because Java has a SortedDictionary (does it, even?) and .NET has a SortedDictionary that they are a paste-in-from-some-converter-website corollary of each other. A lot of changes have occurred to each language in the last 20 years; converting them is highly manual

Comment: In addition to what the others are say here,  would also pay you check out access modifiers vs Dim .  You might find Private doesn’t mean exactly what you think it does

Comment: @CaiusJard, no I'm not. `Option Strict On` requires that you specify a type for all variables. That can be done implicitly via inference on local variables or it can be done explicitly. Member variables require explicit specification as type inference is not supported. In the original code, type inference would have occurred if `oEnvironMap` were a local variable but, as it was a member, it defaulted to type `Object`.

Comment: @jmcilhninney: your comment is the best that I can read. I will now add some explanations directly in my question because what you write 'Member variables require explicit specification as type inference is not supported' is not correct. Wait 10 minutes before reading my last post in question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no probs, just wanted to clarify when you said *every variable* what kinds of variables you were talking about, and also what you meant by *specify the type* - to me a variable that is typed by inference is not a variable that has had its type specified (directly by the programmer)

Comment: @schlebe I don't understand your latest edit and how it relates to your question. You've said `Private x As StreamReader` thus explicitly declared the type of x to be StreamReader, and you're complaining that `Private y = New Dictionary(of..)` is typing as object, but `Private x = New StreamReader` would also type as object if Option Strict is Off and fail to compile with it On. Long story short; turn Option Strict On and fix all the errors it causes. It will make everything better in the end despite causing a raft of errors at the start

Comment: Now I have use Regex type as example. Can you read again. Sorry for my previous Edit that it is not a good example!

Comment: *Member variables require explicit specification as type inference is not supported* is more than correct, it's a must. You can shorten it with `Private oEnvironMap As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)`, but you need `As` there, in a way or another, otherwise (with `Option Strict Off` which you must remove immediately, possibly also setting `Option Explicit On`) you'll have all `Object` types. What you think is a problem - the errors that appear with `Option Strict On` - is instead the solution to  problems you'll have later, problems hard(er) to debug.

Comment: @schlebe and now you've added *another* variation which is `Private x As New StreamReader` which is shorthand for `Private x As StreamReader = New StreamReader` and follows all the rules still

Comment: @Jimi: your comment is good answer for me. I must use 'As' instead of '='. I have tested and this work. What is strange is that '=' work with 'dim' but not with 'Private' or 'Public'. But what is also strange is that compiler doesn't return any error. I will accept your comment as answer if your write it !

Comment: @schlebe the problem with giving you a rule like "use As instead of =" is that it doesn't really give any appreciation for what is going on or why it works. Better that an answer doesn't just give you a rule to follow but explains the back story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are various ways you can make a variable in VB. I'll pick on something basic such as making a new string out of a single char `c` so on the right hand side we always have "a string"

```
Private s = New String("c"c, 1) 's is Object, compilation fails if Option Strict On even if Option Infer On
Private t As New String("c"c, 1) 't is String, shorthand of below
Private u As String = New String("c"c, 1) 'u is String

Private Sub Blah()

    Dim x = New String("c"c, 1) 'x is Object if Option Infer Off, and fails to compile with Option Strict On but succeeds if Off. x is String if Option Infer On and compilation succeeds regardless of Option Strict
    Dim y As New String("c"c, 1) 'y is String, shorthand of below
    Dim z As String = New String("c"c, 1) 

End Sub
```

It's perhaps important to draw a distinction between the Private member variable s and the local Dim'd variable x.

With Option Strict Off and Infer Off, all these will compile, but `s` and `x` will be Object, intellisense will only show you Object members. VB will figure things out at runtime and treat them as strings but you get an error if you try to use things that aren't available on String (it's still a string, just "looks like Object")

With Option Strict On and Infer Off, s and x will fail to compile, and you need to use "As" somewhere to get them typed as a string. Intellisense will then work because the compiler resolves the variables to strings because they've been As'd

With Option Infer On, you can get away with writing `Dim x = ...` because the infer will look at the right hand side and see it's a string, and type x as string for you, but it's only true for `Dim`'d local variables, not class member variables. This means that having Strict On and Infer On you still get a compiler error but this time only on the `Private s` because it hasn't been `As`'d and Infer didn't `As` it for you

---

And all this is unrelated to generic types - anything that mentions X(Of...) - you can swap out the `New String("c"c, 1)` for `New Dictionary(Of String, Int)` and experience all the same rules

---

The behavior of your vs is thus:

```
Private oEnvironMap = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
```

Strict is off, Infer is irrelevant, oEnvironMap is an Object and no compiler errors will occur because VB puts it down as "gotta figure that one out at runtime". At runtime, turns out `isEmpty` ain't a thing -> exception

If you give it a type with either:

```
Private oEnvironMap As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
Private oEnvironMap As SortedDictionary(Of String, String) = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
```

Suddenly the *compiler* knows it's a dictionary, and starts figuring out all the errors (that would have happened at runtime before) now at compile time instead. It can now tell you "isEmpty ain't a thing" as part of the compilation. Every single one of those error in the output window is something that would have caused an exception at runtime with the earlier form. This isn't a "OMG I added one thing and suddenly a hundred errors appeared - that must have been the wrong thing to do"; the errors were always waiting to happen

Turning Option Strict On would have simply enforced that you did either of these latter two.

Comment: It is a good answer. Sorry for my last example with Regex that is not correct and that I have removed.I vote up.

Comment: @schlebe no problem. I added a bit more to the end of the answer to tailor to the specific question about the dictionary too

Answer (score 0):

There are three options in VB that are relevant here and you should understand what each does.

`Option Explicit` is actually the one that can allow implicit declarations. It is `On` by default and should NEVER be turned `Off`. When `Off`, you can introduce a variable in your code without prior declaration. When `On` you MUST declare every variable before use.

`Option Infer` is fairly new and was introduced with LINQ to support anonymous types. When `Off`, all variables must have their data types specified explicitly or, where it is allowed, they will default to type `Object`. When `On`, the type of a variable can be specified implicitly by initialising the variable where it is declared. Whatever the return type of that expression will be type inferred for the variable. It is `On` by default and should probably be left that way but it can be turned `Off` if you won't be using anonymous types and don't mind explicitly specifying the type of every variable. Type inference is not supported for member variables.

`Option Strict` is a big bone of contention. It is `Off` by default, mainly to facilitate upgrade of VB6 code but also to make the language more forgiving for beginners. You should turn it `On` in the properties of any existing projects and also in the IDE options so that it will be `On` by default for all future projects. When `Off`, you are permitted to omit any data type specification for any variable, property or method and they will default to `Object` unless type inference is possible. You are also permitted to rely on implicit conversions when setting variables or properties or passing method arguments. Late binding is also permitted, i.e. accessing members that the compiler cannot confirm exist and must be confirmed at run time. That is all bad in almost every situation. `Option Strict` should be `On` by default so you are forced to always specify and use the correct data type. In the very rare situations where late binding is required, you can turn if `Off` at the file level in the minimum of files containing the minimum of code that actually requires it.

In your particular case, the issue is that you have `Option Strict Off` and so your variable is type `Object`. That regardless of `Option Infer` because type inference is not supported for fields. The compiler doesn't know what members the object it refers to will have so it lets you do anything. You try to access a member that doesn't but that is determined until run time.

Turn `Option Strict On`, specify the type of that field and then only use members in your code that that type actually has, which will be enforced by the compiler instead of being deferred until run time.

Answer (score -1):

I know this will not answer the question of 'implicit variable', but may help to solve the problem of OP.

As the comments say, there is no such Method in .net for the type [SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1)

You will need to test the 'Count' Property  - it will throw Exception if your object is Nothing (null in C#)

Or you could use one of the [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?category=Reference&scope=.NET&terms=linq)-Functions of .net

e.g.
import Linq (make sure `System.Linq.dll` is referenced)

```
Imports System.Linq
```

and test your Dictionary

```
If Not oEnvironMap.Any() Then
  'is empty
end if
```

Comment: sorry, but your response doesn't answer to my question. I have already used Count() before posting this question.

Comment: Yeah, I started with that. :-) Thanks for commenting your downvote! +1